# Whats the most efficient way in C# to cut off the first 4 bytes of a file?

Tags: c#, file-io, arrays

I have a compressed (LZMA) .txt file and need to decompress it, but i have to exclude the first 4 bytes as they are not part of the file content.

I load my file like this:

```
byte[] curFile = File.ReadAllBytes(files[i]);
```

Performance is critical as i have to loop trough over 14k+ files, average file size is around 4KB.

Comment: As in, a FileStream that ignores/skips the first 4 bytes?

Comment: @Flowx, no, a normal `FileStream`. Just `Seek` to position 4, then read the rest of the stream.

Comment: you can get the length of the file and then set the origin and end locations using filestream Seek.

Comment: Yes, as in open a `FileStream` and skip the first 4 bytes. `File.ReadAllBytes` is internally implemented using a `FileStream`: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,ee8033fcb7e7a677 . You can take that code and add a block to skip the first 4 bytes (or better yet, pass a parameter with the number of bytes to skip).

Comment: Whay do think you have to exclude the frist 4 bytes? Can it be [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: @JackA. That sounds very reasonable, thank you. I am fairly new to .NET, would it make sense to use 'File.ReadAsync' ?

Comment: To maximize performance you can consider async and multithreading. I'd just get it working first and decide at that point if the performance is acceptable or needs further tuning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < filePath.Length; i++)
{
    var positionToSkipTo = 4;
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        fileStream.Seek(positionToSkipTo, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var curFile = new byte[fileStream.Length - positionToSkipTo];
        fileStream.Read(curFile, 0, curFile.Length);
        //Do your thing
    }
}
```

Everything is self-explanatory. Important functions are listed at [MSDN FileStream class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Turns out the library im using to decompress my file (7zip SDK) needs a Stream object anyway. I simply used the Seek function to skip the first 4 bytes, then went on with ReadByte.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using a byte array, you can utilize the ConstrainedCopy method in the Array class.

```
Array.ConstrainedCopy(unclippedArray, 4, clippedArray, 0, unclippedArray.Length - 4);
```

If you're not going to just be dealing with the raw bytes, utilize a memory stream and a binary reader or a filestream like other people suggested.